# Failed use apigwManagementApi.postToConnection in $connect route

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to return connectionId to a client after the client connect to aws websocket.

I'm using apigwManagementApi.postToConnection to send a response to a client, but I always get an absurd error message.

I already try to debug & search in google, but I can't find a solution for this.

patch.js

```
require('aws-sdk/lib/node_loader');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk/lib/core');
var Service = AWS.Service;
var apiLoader = AWS.apiLoader;

apiLoader.services['apigatewaymanagementapi'] = {};
AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi = Service.defineService('apigatewaymanagementapi', ['2018-11-29']);
Object.defineProperty(apiLoader.services['apigatewaymanagementapi'], '2018-11-29', {
  get: function get() {
    var model = {
      "metadata": {
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-29",
        "endpointPrefix": "execute-api",
        "signingName": "execute-api",
        "serviceFullName": "AmazonApiGatewayManagementApi",
        "serviceId": "ApiGatewayManagementApi",
        "protocol": "rest-json",
        "jsonVersion": "1.1",
        "uid": "apigatewaymanagementapi-2018-11-29",
        "signatureVersion": "v4"
      },
      "operations": {
        "PostToConnection": {
          "http": {
            "requestUri": "/@connections/{connectionId}",
            "responseCode": 200
          },
          "input": {
            "type": "structure",
            "members": {
              "Data": {
                "type": "blob"
              },
              "ConnectionId": {
                "location": "uri",
                "locationName": "connectionId"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "ConnectionId",
              "Data"
            ],
            "payload": "Data"
          }
        }
      },
      "shapes": {}
    }
    model.paginators = {
      "pagination": {}
    }
    return model;
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});

module.exports = AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi;
```

index.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
require('./patch.js');


exports.handler = async(event) => {
    const connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;

    const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
      apiVersion: '2018-11-29',
      endpoint: event.requestContext.domainName + '/' + event.requestContext.stage
    });

    await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection({ ConnectionId: connectionId, Data: connectionId }).promise();

    return {};
};
```

client.js

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://****');

  ws.on('open', () => {
    console.log('connected ===================>')
    ws.on('message', data => console.warn(`From server: ${data}`));
  });
```

Error in cloudwatch

```
{
    "errorMessage": "410",
    "errorType": "UnknownError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Object.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)",
        "Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:52:8)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
        "Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)"
    ]
}
```

I don't know why, but if I'm trying in a custom route, this code can work.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Wow, I'm literally trying to do this exact same thing. My hunch is that the $connect route is available before the actual connection has been fully established, meaning that any attempt to post to that connection is going to fail. Did you ever figure out a way around this error?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to look into [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/websocket-connect-route-subprotocol.html) example from AWS, there is on connect response for subprotocol confirmation, but I think any payload can be provided.
The most important bit is the route integration settings in the template, basically, the following two lines in the route integration properties:

```
  IntegrationMethod: POST
  ConnectionType: INTERNET
```

then response will be sent to the connected client.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to make this work is to use a DynamoDB table to store connections, then set up a trigger from the table back to a Lambda function.

There are a few catches though. This Lambda function wont work like your index.js file above. You'll have to use NPM install --save aws-sdk on a folder with your index.js file, zip it and upload it to the lambda function, so that the SDK is localized.

You will also need to set up a user with proper access and put the credentials into a your Lambda function.

Note, if you see a 410 error, that means the connection is no longer there, so you're going in the right direction at that point.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
require('./patch.js');
var log = console.log;

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "YOURDATAHERE",
    secretAccessKey: "YOURDATAHERE"
  });

let send = undefined;

function init() {
  const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
    apiVersion: '2018-11-29',
    endpoint: "HARDCODEYOURENDPOINTHERE"
  });
  send = async (connectionId, data) => {

        await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection({ ConnectionId: connectionId, Data: `${data}` }).promise();

  }
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    init();
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    for (const record of event.Records) {
        //console.log(record.eventID);
        console.log(record.eventName);
        console.log('DynamoDB Record: %j', record.dynamodb);
        if(record.eventName == "INSERT"){
            var connectionId = record.dynamodb.NewImage.connectionId.S;
                try{
                    await send(connectionId, connectionId);
                }catch(err){
                    log("Error", err);
                }      
            log("sent");
        }
    }
    return `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`;
};
```